# Copy some MySQL rows between two different database connection via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to copy some rows from srcdb.srctb to dstdb.dsttb that, those are in do separate servers with different user and password access. Due to in PHP we can use one connection resource in `mysql_query()`, how can I do run my query? for example:

```
$dblink_src = ($srchost, $srcuser, $srcpass);
$dblink_dst = ($dsthost, $dstuser, $dstpass);
mysql_query('insert into dstdb.dsttb select * from srcdb.srctb as mysrc where mysrc.provid=8', ????);
```

I don't know what should I put instead of "????" because, I can just use one database connection, but I need 2 to specify two different database connection.

Comment: SELECT INTO OUTFILE in one. LOAD DATA INFILE in the other. Don't need to write any code. Specially not code that uses mysql_*

Answer (score 0):

If this is the same host, you have to replace `????` by a user who have access to the twice databases.

```
$dblink = mysql_connect($srchost,$userWithAccessToSrcAndDest,$pass);

mysql_query('insert into dstdb.dsttb select * from srcdb.srctb as mysrc where mysrc.provid=8',$dblink);
```

I this is two different host, or if there is no user with access to the source and destination databases, you have to use `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` in source database and `LOAD DATA INFILE` in the destination database like mentionned by @e4c5.

Please, think to use `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` functions

Here is another solution using federated table :

On the first server, create a view of your table :

```
create view test_view as
select * from srcdb.srctb as mysrc where mysrc.provid=8
```

On the destination server, create a federated view :

```
CREATE TABLE federated_table (
    //Put your description 
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='mysql://src_user@src_host:3306/src_database/test_view';
```

You could find more explanation about the syntax on this [Mysql chapter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-create-connection.html)

Comment: Thank you dear for your answer and the suggestion. So, any way to do that via sql command line in one query statement without using export and import to/from file?

Comment: This isn't the same host ?

Comment: No, those are in separate hosts.

Comment: Ok, so I edited my answer with federated table. If you can't create table on source host, as far as I now, there is any other way to do that.

Comment: Thank you Alexandre, the federated table solution is helpful for me.